# Searching for a vaccine vs searching for poor genes in the covid-19 pandemic

Tags: genetics, covid

I have only basic knowledge about biology. I have some propositions (may be wrong) and a question about the covid-19 pandemic.

In 1918, the world had a similar pandemic, the Spanish Flu. Millions of people died because of natural selection. Poor genes on flu were eliminated and strong genes survived. Nowadays flu is just an ordinary disease for people because we are the generation of strong genes and our genes are also strong for flu.

Similarly, for the Covid-19 pandemic, poor genes are getting eliminated unfortunately. (I think Covid-19 disease will be just as ordinary as flu in 5-10 years.) For almost 2 years, people have worked for vaccines and we learned that the mortality ratio of Covid-19 is nearly %3 by statistical data.

My question is, instead of quarantining all people for almost 2 years, trying to find a vaccine for almost 2 years and trying to vaccinate all people (only %3 of people are under a death risk), couldn't we just had searched for a pattern for poor genes? So that we might have to quarantine only those with poor genes and might have searched for a cure or vaccine for them?

Is anyone working on something like this, or am I thinking too simply for such a complex problem?

Comment: Wow, just wow...

Comment: The immune response in those that are going to die isn't trackable to a few genes but the interacting expression of hundreds of genes - so not predictable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately your assumptions are almost completely incorrect.

The reasons some get sick and die and others don't are multi(multi)factorial. There will be some [genetic component](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3899649/), but also things like prior exposure to similar disease(s),[socio-economic status](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7756168/), [health status](https://ourworldindata.org/mortality-risk-covid#case-fatality-rate-of-covid-19-by-preexisting-health-conditions), [age](https://ourworldindata.org/mortality-risk-covid#case-fatality-rate-of-covid-19-by-age) (this is a big one for COVID-19), all play into it.

The 1918 H1N1 influenza outbreak had a large number of confounding factors - it was in the middle of a global war, with large numbers of people (especially troops) crowding together (e.g. transport boats, barracks), often in terrible conditions (trenches), large portions of the world (esp. western Europe, China, Korea, parts of Africa)  being refugees with poor nutrition, stress etc.

In addition it was at the very beginnings of modern medicine - there were no antibiotics to take care of the following bacterial infections, no supportive medicine, no respirators etc. The people largely killed by the 1918 H1N1 were young men in [their prime](https://www.cdc.gov/flu/pandemic-resources/1918-pandemic-h1n1.html) (20-40 y), who succumbed to something known as a [cytokine storm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cytokine_storm), where their immune response was actually super strong (too strong) and they died from the resulting inflammation. There is a fairly large school of thought that says that the [same is happening with COVID-19](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7527296/). It is thought that the cytokine storm against H1N1 is actually a heightened immune response because of [prior exposure to another influenza virus](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2927395/). So, these people actually have "good" immune genes, but were the ones killed off by the virus.

Secondly - "just search for poor genes" - you are advocating for something that a) we don't yet know all the genes involved in immune responses, and b) segregation of the population based on genetic characteristics (now where have I heard of that happening before...[here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apartheid), [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racial_segregation), [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuremberg_Laws)); might have some sort of impingement on things like [human rights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_rights), especially when you consider that age is one of the largest factors for COVID-19 death.

Now those 3 comparisons above are a lot shitty, because those were horrific things done with no just cause, and you *could* make an argument that those more at risk of COVID-19 should take more precautions (as many do) - but how do you enact that into law? How do you enforce it? Can you tell if someone walking down the street has diabetes or asthma and are thus more at risk?

Comment: thanks for the answer.as you suggest maybe it would be better to inform someone whether he/she is in more danger. and i think its just same as to inform a diabetes patient to not eat sugary foods. i think law and human rights for this case are another topic of argument

Comment: @M.SEL that's exactly what happened in countries with good health care systems (and almost all other countries), public health advisories were made for those more at risk, efforts were made to protect the elderly and unwell by prioritising them for vaccines, isolating aged care facilities, mandating masks (which is about protecting not just yourself but others too) and social distancing, shutdowns/lockdowns - these are all effective public health measures that worked in many places. That some people chose to ignore advice from experts does not reflect on advice given, but on the individual.